# QGIS legend in layout manager

Tags: qgis, legend, offset, layout-manager

I have offset some data points in QGIS but I want my points to stay aligned in the legend? It looks funny when points aren't lined up. Anyway I can do this?

[image]

Comment: can you post a screen capture of the issue?

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using?

Comment: This is a guess, but is there an X offset on the symbols?

Answer (score 1):

When I have some funky symbology like this I usually create a folder in my table of contents called "Legend Layers", in that I create duplicates of my layers which have symbology that doesn't look good in the legend. I use these duplicates to change the symbology to something that looks good in the legend and then I add those to the legend instead of the original layers.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is to use a geometry generator style.

Under the Marker symbology, change Symbol layer type to 'Geometry generator', select Point/Multipoint as the Geometry type, then paste in an expression like `translate($geometry, 0.2, -0.2)` to offset the point (change the numeric values as needed, these are X and Y offsets in the CRS of the layer), then style the marker for that point appropriately.

[image]

However, a big caveat is that you can only offset using map units, not millimeters etc. - which is a pain if you're using a geographic coordinate system (like EPSG:4326 - you might need to convert the point geometry to a projected system)

Also a pain if you want it to offset a similar amount at different scales. You would have to play around based on the map scale you want - in the above I've used 0.2 and -0.2 in metres to approximate a 2mm X/Y offset at 1:100 in a local projected coordinate system... but it's again different at 1:50 - see below.

The marker appears properly in the legend, at least, so if you know what scale you want it at, you can fix the values and only have it display at that particular scale?

[image]