# Cannot change legend shape in print layout of QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend, layouts

I am using QGIS 3.x.

I would like to customize the legend in my print layout. Unfortunately I am quite restricted, as I can't change my shape appearance.

According to the link below:

https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/composer_items/composer_legend.html

it looks like I can only change the height or width of my shapes.

[image]

I have some symbols, which I would like to appear as circles instead of rectangles or thick lines.

There is some solution at [Is it possible to change legend symbols in the QGIS print composer legend?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229617/is-it-possible-to-change-legend-symbols-in-the-qgis-print-composer-legend) but it looks like I need some Python skills for it.

Is there any simple way to customize the legend symbol one by one in the print layout area or should I go back to the geometry generator style and do something like at [QGIS legend in layout manager](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/352638/qgis-legend-in-layout-manager)?

Comment: Circular symbols should appear as such in the legend.  Did you resize it and have it show as rectangular, and where did the line come from in the legend?  If the circular symbol is too large for the patch size one workaround is to duplicate the layer and put the duplicate under the other (to hide it) with a smaller symbol size, and use that one in the legend.

Comment: You can check out this video about Legend Patches in QGIS: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IL21scLDKOc

Answer (score 3):

Since version 3.14 the legend patch size or shape are customizable :

**From the 3.14 changelog:**

- -[overriding the legend patch size on a per-item basis](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog314/#id53)
- -[Feature: Manage legend patch shapes through style manager](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog314/#id55)
- -[Feature: Allow configuring legend patch shapes by double-clicking on legend items](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog314/#id56)

**From the 3.22 version documentation :**

[Customizing legend items](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/composer_items/composer_legend.html?highlight=legend#customizing-legend-items)

Answer (score 0):

Polygons will always show as rectangles in the print layout. A simple way to get a circle in the legend is create a point layer with the symbol shape you like. Edit the symbology in Simple-Fill as transparent fill and width and color of the stroke (border). Then increase the size. Name this as LayerNameSymbol (or whatever you'd like). In the print layout as a legend item select this layer and change the name to your Layer Name. Now you will have a Circular Symbol in the legend (if this is what you were looking for).

[image: Print Layout with Circular Legend Item Symbol]